Android Studio problem with lambda expression
I am trying to make a function that returns the longitude and latitude in the form of a string. I cannot for the life of me figure out why:

the lambda function refuses to update the value please to the actual coordinates (the function does actually manage to get the location because if i uncomment that line with Log it does actually post some coords)
Avoid the lambda function altogether if possible (problem 1 being solved has priority over this)

fun getLatLongString(location: Location?): String {
    val latitude = location?.latitude
    val longitude = location?.longitude
    return "Latitude: $latitude, Longitude: $longitude"
}

// @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
fun getLocation():String {
    var please = "no location"
    val task: Task<Location> = fusedLocationClient.lastLocation

    task.addOnSuccessListener { location: Location? -> String
        if (location != null) {
            var latLongString:String = getLatLongString(location)
            please = latLongString
            //Log.i("I", "Location $please")
        }else{
            please = "location not working"
            Log.i("I", "Location not found")
        }
    }
    return please
}

these are my 2 functions. The first one getLatLongString simply formats and transforms the data and the second function getLocation is the main function that handles the gathering of location.
Any help is greatly appreciated!!
P.S. there is a error on the line where the task is declared but that error is related to missing permissions which i handled somewhere else.

your problem is "asynchronous"... your current code creates request for location, adds some listener for future response and returns always null please. This please will got lat/long cords (or "not working") after getLocation() method returns please result
a solution for your case might be suspend function in Kotlin, which will wait for all asynchronous tasks before return
some code sample:
suspend fun getLocation(): String = suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
    val fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(requireContext())
    val task: Task<Location> = fusedLocationClient.lastLocation

    task.addOnSuccessListener { location: Location? ->
        if (location != null) {
            val latLongString = getLatLongString(location)
            continuation.resume(latLongString)
        } else {
            continuation.resume("location not working")
        }
    }

    task.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
        continuation.resumeWithException(exception)
    }

    continuation.invokeOnCancellation {
        task.cancel()
    }
}

beware of suspend - this is doing what it means, it suspends method execution. if you are providing button calling this method - it's "press anim" (e.g. ripple effect) may stuck for few millis (secs?) as your suspending method is during execution

Your function adds a listener and returns before the listener has a chance to update the returned value.
To simplify work with play services' Task in kotlin, you can use this library. It adds suspendable Task.await function.
Dependency:
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.9.0")

Function:
// @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
suspend fun getLocation(context: Context): String = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val locationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)
    val result: Location? = locationClient.lastLocation.await()
    if (result == null) {
        "location not working"
    } else {
        getLatLongString(result)
    }
}

Example usage:
var location by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
val context = LocalContext.current
Column {
    Text(location)
    Button(onClick = {
        scope.launch {
            location = getLocation(context)
        }
    }) {
        Text("Get last location")
    }
}

